# How can I separate negative zero from positive zero?

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, zero, negative-zero

I want to be able to test if zero is positive or negative in swift.

```
let neg: CGFloat = -0
let pos: CGFloat = +0

if pos == neg {
    // this gets executed, but I don't want this
}
```

The code above does not work like I need it to. Can someone help me?

Comment: When would you need to know positive vs negative 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are “negative zero” and “positive zero” floating point numbers.
You can disambiguate them by checking the `.sign` property, but they
(intentionally) compare as equal:

```
let neg: CGFloat = -0.0
let pos: CGFloat = +0.0

print(neg.sign) // minus
print(pos.sign) // plus
print(neg == pos) // true

if (neg == pos && neg.sign == pos.sign) {
    // This is not executed.
}
```

Note that you have to use floating point literals ("-0.0" or "+0.0")
in the initialization. The integer literals ("+0", "-0") are equal
and converted to positive zero.

Comment: Thank you ;) Worked out for me

Answer (score 1):

Basically, from the ordinary arithmetic point view both `neg` and `pos` are *identical zeros*, therefore `if pos == neg` is true.

However, when it comes to representing a floating-point number, `CGFloat` has [`sign`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/1845206-sign) property as `FloatingPointSign` enum:

> minus if the sign bit of self is set, and plus otherwise. Implements
>   the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) sign bit operation.

Therefore, your if-statement would be:

```
if neg.sign == pos.sign { } // false
```